# JRE set but not executing while installing Oracle 11g in windows

Tags: java, oracle

[image]I am installing oracle in windows for which it is asking jre. I have set the Environment variables using system setting and also set the path for bin folder where jawaw is installed but still its showing same error .JRE not found in bin\jawaw.exe
 while in CMD javaw is executing fine.

the version of JRE which i installed is 1.7.

thanks
Prateek

Comment: Can you post the screen shot of you enviroment variables?

Comment: I strongly suspect your JAVA_HOME is pointing to the bin folder.

Comment: i missed that, oracle 10g :(

Comment: try providing JRE Location with the command `./runInstaller -jreLoc JRE_LOCATION` as mentioned here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/doc.1111/e15017/install_osb.htm
Also, share the values of your PATH and JAVA_HOME. Just run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %PATH%` from a newly opened command prompt

Comment: The Oracle installer comes with it's own JRE. You usually don't need an "external" one. Try _removing_ all those environment variables. @Pat: the Windows installer is `setup.exe` not `runInstaller`

Comment: Hi Darshan i have posted screen shot of environment variables and error i am getting.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work even after setting JAVA_HOME and you continue to get this error, this means that the installable you are using is corrupt. Try using some other installable. Same thing happended in my case and when i downloaded another setup and ran it, it worked perfectly fine. Hope it resolved you issue too.